# Xml HTTP Request to the server

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет. 
Наткнулся на проблему при запросе, получаю ошибку.. 
Что такое Access control check? В чём проблема ? 
Буду рад любой помощи.

При передачи данных с формы в RegisterController нету проблем.. Но при запросе получаю ошибку.

```js
function registerHandler(user){

  //Error in Ajax request

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(xhr.readyState!=4 || xhr.status!=200){
        return window.alert("Problems with request");
    }
   }

    xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:8080/CouponOnWeb/webappl/register",true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json;charset=utf-8');
    xhr.send(user);
}

function registerController(){


    var user = {

    username:document.getElementById("reg_user_name").value,
    firstname:document.getElementById("first_name").value,
    lastname:document.getElementById("last_name").value,
    userid:document.getElementById("user_id").value,
    password:document.getElementById("reg_password").value,
    email:document.getElementById("reg_email").value

    }

   registerHandler(user);

   }
```

```html
 <form id = "registrator" onsubmit = "registerController()">
  
  <label for = "reg_user_name">User name:</label>
  <input id = "reg_user_name" name = "reg_user_name" type = "text" placeholder = "user name">
  <br>
  <label for = "first_name">First name:</label>
  <input id = "first_name" name = "first_name" type = "text" placeholder = "first name">
  <br>
  <label for = "last_name">Last name:</label>
  <input id = "last_name" name = "last_name" type = "text" placeholder = "last name">
  <br>
  <label for = "user_id">Id number:</label>
  <input id = "user_id" name = "user_id" type = "number" placeholder = "id number">
  <br>
  <label for = "reg_password">Password:</label>
  <input id = "reg_password" name = "reg_password" type = "password" placeholder = "password">
  <br>
  <label for = "reg_email">Email:</label>
  <input id = "reg_email" name = "reg_email" type = "email" placeholder = "email">
  <br>
  <input id = "reg_button" name = "reg_button" type = "submit" value = "Register">


  </form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это означает, что вы совершаете запрос с одного домена на другой. На другом домене нужно разместить заголовок:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your_domain.com
```

или совершать запросы на одном и том же домене.

В гугле есть куча материалов на эту тему.

Comment: Андрей - можешь кинуть ссылку на материал как раз по моей теме ?
В инете всего куча, но если знаком с этой проблемой скорее всего знаешь что мне нужно.

Comment: Я уже вам написал. Вам необходимо либо разместить заголовок, либо осуществлять запросы в пределах одного домена. Например вы с localhost:300 совершаете запрос на localhost:301, это разные домены и будет исключение.